# utf8 encoding not same between flutter and dart

Tags: node.js, dart, sha256

I want to hash in sha256 a string in Nodejs and in dart here are my code . My string of test is 'Test'

```
    String password = 'Test';
    List<int> ut8encoded = utf8.encode(password);// give [84,101,115,116]
    String pass = sha256.convert(ut8encoded).toString();give 532eaabd9574880dbf76b9b8cc00832c20a6ec113d682299550d7a6e0f345e25
```

in Node js:

```
let crypto = require('crypto');
    let string_utf8 =  Buffer.from(string, 'utf8');//give <Buffer 54 65 73 74>
    console.log(string_utf8);
    let hash = crypto.createHash('sha256').digest(string_utf8).toString('hex');
//give e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
```

I can't understand why i receive two different buffer int and hash .

If someone can explain me :)

I trie to put same List in the both sha256 but even with this the hash isn't the same

Answer (score 0):

You need to read [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#class-hash) for the Node crypto APIs you're using. The parameter passed to `.digest()` is *not* the data to be hashed, but the (optional) encoding of the output. You use `.update()` to add data to be hashed. Your JS code is effectively outputting the SHA256 hash of an nothing.

You probably want something like:

```js
let crypto = require('crypto');
let hash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(your_string, 'utf8').digest('hex');
console.log(hash);
```